# Recovering a signal after nonuniform sampling

Tags: fourier-transform, sampling, continuous-signals, nonuniform

Let $x(t)$ be a bandlimited signal such that $X(j\omega) =0 $ when $|\omega|>M$. Also $p(t) = p_1(t) - p_1(t-\Delta)$ is a nonuniformly spaced periodic pulse train where $$p_1(t) = \sum_{k = -\infty}^{+\infty}\delta\left(t - \frac{2\pi k}{M}\right), \quad \text{with}\quad \Delta= \frac{\pi}{2M}$$
[image]

Let $x_p(t) = x(t)p(t)$ and apply an ideal low-pass filter with cutoff frequency $\omega_c = M$ to $X_p(j\omega)$. The result is $z(t)$. Design a system which recovers $x(t)$ from $z(t)$.

[image]

**My try:**

It's easy to see that
$$P(j\omega) = \left(1 - e^{-j\Delta \omega}\right)\left(M\sum_{k = -\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(\omega - kM)\right) = M\sum_{k = -\infty}^{+\infty}\left(1 - e^{-j\Delta kM}\right)\delta(\omega - kM)
$$

Also we have

$$
X_p(j\omega) = \frac{1}{2\pi}X(j\omega)\star P(j\omega) = \frac{M}{2\pi}\sum_{k = -\infty}^{+\infty}\left(1 - e^{-j\Delta kM}\right)X\big(j(\omega - kM)\big)
$$

Since $\Delta= \frac{\pi}{2M}$ we have
$$
X_p(j\omega) = \frac{M}{2\pi}\sum_{k = -\infty}^{+\infty}\left(1 - e^{\frac{-jk\pi}{2}}\right)X\big(j(\omega - kM)\big)
$$

After low-pass filter we get

$$
Z(j\omega) = \begin{cases}
\frac{M}{2\pi}\bigg[(1+j)X\big(j(\omega - M)\big) + (1-j)X\big(j(\omega + M)\big)\bigg],  & \lvert \omega\rvert < M\\
0, & \text{O.W}
\end{cases}
$$

I've got stuck here. How can we recover $x(t)$? I tried to use phase shifter and $z(t)\cos(Mt)$ but it didn't work.

Comment: all's i can say, by just glancing at this, is that you will not be able to recover the DC component of the signal being sampled.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Why is recovering DC component impossible?

Comment: because the DC component of $x_p(t)$ is always zero, independent of the DC in $x(t)$.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson I see. Do you have any idea for recovering $x(t)$ from $z(t)$?

Comment: it requires that i look at this more.  as best as i can tell, you can recovered the spectrum of $x(t)$, (which is $X(j\omega)$) everywhere except where the spectrum was multiplied by zero.  you just can't divide by zero.

Comment: [Possibly relevant](https://arxiv.org/abs/1006.2533); I don't know much further, though.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Thanks but I think there should be an easy answer to this question since it's an ordinary exercise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with your result for $Z(j\omega)$. Apart from scaling, what you have is the original spectrum with positive and negative frequencies swapped and multiplied with factors $1-j$ and $1+j$, respectively. In order to restore the original signal, we need to add right-shifted and left-shifted versions of the spectrum, while getting rid of the complex factors. Final lowpass filtering removes the redundant components in the frequency range $[M,2M]$.

The necessary shifting and complex scaling is achieved by multiplication with

$$e^{jMt}(1+j)+e^{-jMt}(1-j)=2\cos(Mt)-2\sin(Mt)\tag{1}$$

Modulation with $(1)$, lowpass filtering with cut-off frequency $M$, and appropriate scaling restores the original signal.

Comment: Thanks. I think we need to construct $z(t)\sin(M t)$ as well, because $Z(j\omega)$ is limited to $|\omega|<M$. I mean $X(j(\omega + M))$ and $X(j(\omega - M))$ are one-sided spectrum in $Z(j\omega)$, so $z(t)\cos(M t)$ contains two one-sided spectrums of $X(j\omega)$, one of them is multiplied by $1+j$ and the other one is multiplied by $1-j$. Therefore their sum doesn't give $X(j\omega)$.

Comment: @S.H.W I've also observed the sin / cos multiplied  terms and an original term too. But the sin / cos terms can be combined into a single cosine with phase...

Comment: @Fat32 I think $\text{LPF}\{2z(t)\sin(Mt) -2z(t)\cos(Mt)\}$ would work but I'm not sure.

Comment: @S.H.W What I found was $LPF \{ z(t) \cdot \left( 2 \sqrt{2} \cos(Mt+ \pi/4) -1 \right) \}$ which is also  $ LPF \{ z(t) \cdot \left( 2\cos(Mt) - 2 \sin(Mt) -1 \right) \}$. The LPF has a gain of $T$ (just as usual interpolators)

Comment: @Fat32 Thanks. Are you sure that we need $-z(t)$ as well? Also I found the gain to be $-\pi/M$. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @S.H.W oops my $-z(t)$ is reduntant, so yours seems to be correct, hence *apart from a linear scaling factor*, the multiplication on $z(t)$ seems like $\cos(Mt)-\sin(Mt)$ or similarly $\cos(Mt+\pi/4)$.

Comment: @Fat32 Okay, thank you so much.

Comment: @S.H.W: You're right about the sine component, I went a bit too quick. I'll come back later to update and correct my answer.

Comment: @MattL. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @S.H.W: I've updated and corrected my original answer.